# any way to populate random datas into a data base for testing purpose?

Tags: sql, database, testing

I have been searching in StackOverflow, but I only got so far this website http://www.generatedata.com/#generator

but it doesn't support foreign constraints.

is there any software which can full fill a database with a lots of tables?

or the only way is writing my own script?

thanks

Comment: [Redgate Data Generator](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-generator/) I've used it only in Demo mode, didn't buy it as I didnt have repeated use of it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out SQL Data Generator from Red Gate:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-generator/

The features page lists:

- Foreign key support for generating consistent data across multiple tables

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) can be used to generate meaningful test data.

Comment: Well,not really. DBUnit, while great, does not generate data, it can just load and save it in various formats. It will be helpful for programmatically generating data, however.